# Access objects pointed by Foreign keys?  query works fine - How do I access the returned id values?

Tags: django, django-models

This is really simple but I'm having problems solving it with Django:

I have the following models defined:

```
class Story(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.title

class Category(models.Model):
   categoryText = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   parentCat = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)

   def __unicode__(self): 
      return self.categoryText

class StoryCat(models.Model):
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)  

    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.story
```

I'm trying to do query on StoryCat to retrieve all stories that have the same category.  I do the following query:

```
c = Category.objects.get(categoryText='short')
s = StoryCat.objects.filter(category=c)
```

At this point I want to get access to the values within the returned classes but I am not able to figure out how to do it.  Everything I've tried I get an error.  How can I get the number of stories returned and ids of the returned stories?

Comment: may be you could replace your categories by tags. using django-taggit or django-tagging. I know that this is completely different from you want but @John Already answered your question, and i find that this could be simpler

Comment: My question is : The query is working fine - How do I access the id values -

Comment: s.values('id'), and this return a list of dicts, look in the docs ->>  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ids = s.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')  
# [1, 2, 3, ...] 
ids_length = len(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your models seems wrong to me.  First off what you're created is a ManyToMany relationship between stories and categories.  This seems like it *might* be overkill to me, however I could be wrong.

If indeed you are looking to create a manytomany between stories and categories you should define it:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    categories = models.ManyToMany(Category, through=StoryCat)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

From there your query would be like:

```
c = Category.objects.get(id=1)
stories = Story.objects.filter(categories=c)
```

Comment: I purposely did not use many-to-many field since documentation is not clear enough to me.  I haven't found an example of how to retrieve from many to many fields in Django so I went the easy way in my mind.  My issue is that I can't figure out how to get the ids from the returned query.

Comment: The question is : How do I access the id values of the returned stories?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing should work, but it looks like the `story` field of `StoryCat` has a foreign key to the wrong model.  You probably want `Story`, not `Poll`.

By the way, a story could just have a foreign key to `Category` (if a story only has one category), or a [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) relationship to `Category` (if a story can belong to more than one category).  Then you won't need the `StoryCat` model at all.

Comment: I fixed the change from Poll to Story - that was just a mistake when I was copying - One story can have multiple categories.  I am doing the query but I can't figure out how to get the ids of the returned stories!